# could not add a new Object to the Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I use the entity framework to add a new Object to the database.
I use this lines but it didn't add the Object.

```
Location location = new Location() { Standort = "new Location" };
db.Location.Add(location);
db.SaveChanges();
```

the table looks like this.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Location] (
[Id]       INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Standort] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

My connection:

```
private DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities();

<connectionStrings>
<add name="DatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Did you get any error or it doesn't simply add the objet to the database?

Comment: No i get no error and the db.SaveChanges(); methode returns 1.

Comment: Are you sure that you are looking the correct database? Get the connection string from your configuration file and connect to the database using SSMS. Don't you see there the record you have inserted?

Comment: I use a Local DatabaseFile and i use the name from the connectionString.

Comment: Since you use Local Database, you could do this: Inside the visual studio you could selecte to show hidden files (it's a button below the header of Solution Explorer, hover over the buttons and you will find it). Then in AppData folder there should be your database file. By double clicking on it a connection would be established and you could show the data in the tables of your database. Please follow this and let me know what you see. (In order to see the data you navigate to the folder Tables, Right click on your Table and click Show Data).

Comment: I only see my maulay added objects.

Comment: manually??? Where the code you mentioned is used?

Comment: When i show the table data i can add them here also. Thats what i mean by adding them manualy. Sorry it wasn't clear.

Comment: Can you show how you initialize your `db` variable and which context initializer you are using?

Comment: I am also able to add a new Line with the  SQL INSERT INTO Statement

Comment: I could suppose that you have defined a `partial class DatabaseEntities`, which inherits the `DbContext` class and it's constructor is like this `public DatabaseEntities() : base("name=DatabaseEntities") { }`. Correct? Apparently, in the same class you should have a property called `Location`, like this `public virtual DbSet<Location> Location { get; set; }`.Correct ?

Comment: This got automaticly created by the framework